# Flutter - How can I make 2 buttons be as large as the largest of them?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, user-interface, button, layout

I have two `ElevatedButtons` inside a `Row` widget and I need both of them to be the same length but only as large as the largest button.

Here's my current code:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Some long text'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Short'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, one button is much larger than the other one. Is it possible to make the "Short" button as long as the "Some long text" button?
[image]

I figured I could use `Expanded` to make them the same size but I don't want this because I need them to use the least possible length while still being the same size and not needing to shrink one of them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you can wrap the `Row` with the `IntrinsicWidth` widget (and all of the `Row`s children with `Expanded`) and it works as you want, but the description of it says:

> This class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible.

```
IntrinsicWidth(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Some long text'),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Short'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```